# Is this activity designed with cardviews?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I am trying to design a layout similar to the one on the [left image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn3Dd.jpg) .

I thought this was a layout with one `cardview` for each section. However, I tried to put more than one `cardview` inside a `LinearLayout` orientation vertical and I only see one.

Why is that? Are `cardviews` are just meant to be used on `RecyclerViews` lists? If so, how can I achieve a layout design like these?

Comment: Link you xml for the code you attempted to write for the cardviews. They are just viewgroups so the would work as if you were trying to build the layout with linearlayouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference for [CardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html). It is just a RelativeLayout with a rounded corners and a drop shadow. So yes, the image was probably an image of a layout designed with CardViews. At the same time, it could also just be a layout that was custom built and a shadow drawn behind it, if that developer wanted to do the work themselves. You can easily replicate the layout by creating this in xml, I can provide an example if necessary.

The CardView is not JUST designed for RecyclerView's but looks really good in a RecyclerView as the layout that is inflated IF a CardView layout makes sense to use. Again, it's just a RelativeLayout with extra features (rounded edges, and shadow)